# Разбиение строки с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, qt

Как с помощью регулярного выражения разбить строку

```
 name@domain.xxx:pass:w
```

так, чтобы получить второе значение `pass:w`?

Comment: А почему нужно разбивать именно с помощью регулярного выражения?

Comment: @Shamov, нужно ведь брать вторую часть вместе с двоеточием.

Comment: Я именно потому и спрашиваю. Регулярные выражения плохо подходят для строк, в которых один и тот же символ имеет в разных местах разный смысл.

Comment: @Abyx Я вижу совершенно по-другому. Первое двоеточие является разделителем, все последующие - просто символами.

Comment: @Abyx Из чего следует, что `@` - это разделитель? Строка `name@domain.xxx` похожа на email.

Comment: @Shamov, разделитель :

Comment: @MatthewHaig Если `:` - это разделитель, то он сам не может быть частью того, что он же и разделяет.

Comment: @Shamov, so bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверняка существует более практичное решение, но при первом рассмотрении видится что-то вроде такого (для Qt5):

```
QString str("name@domain.xxx:pass:w");
QRegularExpression reg_exp("(.*):(.*:+.*)");
QRegularExpressionMatch match = reg_exp.match(str);
if(match.hasMatch()) {
   QString result = match.captured(2);
}
```

И всё же... регулярные выражения стоит использовать к месту. Эту задачу можно решить и так:

```
QString str("name@domain.xxx:pass:w");
QString result = str.mid(str.indexOf(QLatin1Char(':'))+1);
```

Comment: @Abyx Мой ответ в части регулярного выражения не претендует на универсальность, либо исключительную практичность. Это обозначено достаточно явно в вводной части поста. Просто предложите лучшее решение.

Answer (score -1):

Возможно вам подойдет метод split() . Этот метод сейчас общеизвестен и стал почти стандартным решением для разбивания имея delimiter.

Comment: Только если метод поддерживает ограничение на количество кусков. Иначе собирать из кусков...

Comment: Мешает второе двоеточие.